# extract the images whose has microcontent class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i want to extract images from html whose has "microcontent" class attribute  like i have
        …

i want to extract this images whose class is class="microcontent"

i wrote this code but this is not working.

```
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var title = $('head title').text();
    var keywords = $('head meta[name=keywords]').attr('content');
    var desc = $('head meta[name=description]').attr('content');
    var links = $('a');
    var imgArray = [];

    $('img.microconent').each(function(){

    var temp = $(this).attr("src");
    imgArray.push(temp);
    var downloadImage = function (temp) {
    http.get(temp, function (res) {
    var imagedata = ''
    res.setEncoding('binary')
     res.on('data', function(chunk){
     imagedata +=  chunk;
     });

      res.on('end', function(){
      var imgArr = temp.split("/");
      var Name = util.id();
      imgName = imgArr[imgArr.length-1];
      imgName = imgName.split(".");
      imgName = imgName[imgName.length-1];
      imgName = Name + "." +imgName;
      fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/img/' + Name + ".png" , imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('image saved')
      });

      });
      });
       };
      downloadImage(temp);
     console.log("image is  " + imgArray);
    });
    console.log('Crawling "%s" | %s',title,this.url);
```

any help would be appreciable.

Comment: `$('img . microconent')` should be `$('img .microconent')`

Comment: ok but its not extract micronent class...it will not work..

Comment: My bad, the right syntax for targetting images whose have "microcontent" class attribute is : `$('img.microcontent')` (whithout space)

Comment: ok but @mguimard image now save in folder but its not loaded...

Comment: What do you mean by "not loaded" ? Is it well written on the disk with fs.writeFile ? Do you have any error in your log ?

Comment: i save my images in my folder but its not open i think any buffer problem due too large not of bytes images.. image are not open in jpg format

Answer (score 0):

Dont give space after '.'

you should write it like,

```
`$('img .microcontent')` not like `$('img . microcontent`')
```

Comment: try `$("img[class='microcontent']")`